# iOS - App crash without error during loop process

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, loops, crash

during a loop process, my App crash without error. The array count is equal to 175260. With profiler I don't have leaks, so I don't know why the App exit, maybe the CPU usage 100% during a lot of time?

Thank you for your help.

Just this code following crash the App :

```
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <14;i++)
    {
        if(findSensor[i]==YES)
        {
            for(unsigned int j = 1; j <[array count];j++)
            {
                @autoreleasepool {

                    if([[[[array objectAtIndex:j] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",10*(i+1)]])
                    {
                        //Code here 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The full code is :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,[ibNavSettings interfaceSettings].selectedFileToDataBase];

NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:fileName];

NSFileHandle *output = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@10",documentsDirectory,[ibNavSettings interfaceSettings].selectedFileToDataBase]];

if(output == nil)
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    _recordlocal = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RECORD" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    _recordlocal.date = [ibNavSettings interfaceSettings].selectedFileToDataBase;

    NSData *inputData = [NSData dataWithData:[fh readDataToEndOfFile]];

    NSString *inputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]];


    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <14;i++)
    {
        if(findSensor[i]==YES)
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%d",documentsDirectory,[ibNavSettings interfaceSettings].selectedFileToDataBase,10*(i+1)] contents:nil attributes:nil];

            NSMutableString *saveString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

            int count = 0;

            for(unsigned int j = 1; j <[array count];j++)
            {
                @autoreleasepool {

                    if([[[[array objectAtIndex:j] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",10*(i+1)]])
                    {
                        [saveString appendString:[array objectAtIndex:j]];
                        [saveString appendString:@"\n"];
                        if(i == 0)
                            count++;
                        progress++;
                        pourcent = progress/total;
                        load = pourcent*100;
                        if(load%5==0)
                            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(changeUI:)withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(pourcent)]];


                    }
                }
            }

            [saveString writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%d",documentsDirectory,[ibNavSettings interfaceSettings].selectedFileToDataBase,10*(i+1)] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
            if(i == 0)
                _recordlocal.count = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:(count/50)];
        }

    }

    _recordlocal.load = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:YES];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Core data error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

Comment: What is the //Code here doing? Have you found out what element it crashes on? Maybe just put an NSLog(@"%d", j); in there

Comment: Normally it's a code saving wanted data in a NSMutableString but without this code, the App crash too. Good idea, I will try this.

Comment: Unfortunatly it's a random crash

Comment: It may just be a memory thing then. Do you have any error being shown in Xcode? Maybe something like "unable to allocate ...."

Comment: I don't have error unfortunately and just the code with the loop and the if (not the full code) crash the App... However, if I start my App without debugger, this work and the App doesn't crash.

Comment: Just because it doesn't crash doesn't mean there isn't a problem.  With DEBUG=0, the application attempts to keep going even in an Exception state.  It WILL CRASH for a Fatal Exception.  If it doesn't crash right away, it is likely your application is still in an undefined state, and will probably crash/have buggy behaviour elsewhere.  This is why the debugger crashes you

Comment: I actually just realized something else, if you haven't changed that threading code yet, you should. It is probably a waste to check if you should update your UI 2,000,000+ times.  Only update your UI at the end of each of the 14 iterations, and only make the call to the main thread

Comment: And can you add logs like I suggested, then update your question to point out what line you are actually bombing on

Comment: In fact, only the code with the loop and the condition : `if([[[[array objectAtIndex:j] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",10*(i+1)]])` crash. It's not necessary I add the process code. The crash is randomly during the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that your app is crashing without a readable exception because it is running out of available RAM, especially since you indicated that it is running through a large number of iterations.

For a test, I would recommend doing what Rikkles suggests with the autorelease pool. In addition, since the value of i (and as a result the comparison string) rarely changes, I would create that string outside the j loop as well. This would avoid the creation of a lot of extra strings laying around.

Beyond that, since it appears that you are looking for a string at the beginning of a string that is delimited by a semicolon, I would recommend instead of doing componentsSeparatedByString and then examining element zero that you use the NSString method hasPrefix to check for the condition you are looking for.

Here is an example:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <14;i++)
{
    NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d;", 10*(i+1)];
    if(findSensor[i]==YES)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j <[array count];j++)
        {
            if([[array objectAtIndex:j] hasPrefix:searchString])
            {
                //Code here 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I hope this compiles and runs, if it doesn't it should require more than minor tweaks. I am away from my Mac right now.)

If this doesn't help, then something going on inside //Code here must be the culprit.

Comment: Depending on how large your saveString gets, that could be a problem as well. You might want to write out the file as you go instead of accumulating the string in memory and writing it out at the end. Also, comment out the changeUI selector call for testing to see if that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating `[array count]` autoreleasepools? What's the point of creating so many of them? It could crash because of that. Put the `@autoreleasepool` outside the for loop.
The only reason I could think that you would do that is if you create so many transient objects inside each iteration of the for loop that you'd want to get rid of them as soon as you got out of the iteration. But there are other ways to do that, including reusing those objects within each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

#### First suggestion

Just use fast enumeration for the inner loop, you aren't actually using the index 'j' for anything

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Enumeration.html

#### Second suggestion

Put some NSLog's in place, it will slow everything down, but you need to figure out what point you are failing at.  That will help point everyone in the right direction.

#### Third suggestion

Actually use NSError objects and output their value if an error is thrown:

```
NSError *writeError = nil;
[saveString writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%d",documentsDirectory,[ibNavSettings interfaceSettings].selectedFileToDataBase,10*(i+1)] 
             atomically:YES 
               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                  error:&writeError];
if(error != nil) NSLog(@"error writing file: %@", [[writeError userInfo]description]);
```

#### Fourth suggestion

You appear to try to be updating the UI from a background thread.  This will not work or will cause a crash.  UI code can only be called from a main thread.  So dont do this:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(changeUI:)withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(pourcent)]];
```

If you are already on a background thread this will probably crash because you are creating threads on threads on threads.  You instead would want to call:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeUI:)withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(pourcent)]];
```

#### Fifth suggestion

You may be going over the maximum length for NSString (it's big but I did it once on accident before).  You should probably just be appending the file on each iteration of the loop instead, so you don't have an ever growing NSMutableString:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%d",documentsDirectory,[ibNavSettings interfaceSettings].selectedFileToDataBase,10*(i+1)]
NSFileHandle *fh  = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

NSData *newLine = [@"\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
for(NSString *rowString in array)
{
    if([[[rowString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",10*(i+1)]])
    {
        NSData *stringData = [rowString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [fh truncateFileAtOffset:[fh seekToEndOfFile]];
        [fh writeData:stringData];
        [fh truncateFileAtOffset:[fh seekToEndOfFile]];
        [fh writeData:newLine];
        if(i == 0)
            count++;
        progress++;
        pourcent = progress/total;
        load = pourcent*100;
        if(load%5==0)
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(changeUI:)withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(pourcent)]];


        }
    }
}
```

And this has the added benefit of helping you ditch the autoreleasepools

#### This was invalid

If your array does in fact have 175260 rows, that is probably your issue.  You are looping using unsigned int as your index var.  Unsigned ints in c only have a max value of 65535.  Use an unsigned long int, max 4294967295.

Comment: The max value of `unsigned int` on iOS is `4294967295`, not `65535`.

Comment: Good ideas, thank you :) Concerning the fifth suggestion, the function writeData is too slow, it's for this reason I use it only at the end. Concerning the crash, This is only with the debbuger but the App doesn't crash if I start directly.

Comment: Something else i was thinking about.  You said writeData was too slow, this is probably because it is a Cocoa method.  I am betting if you look into the Unix/POSIX C file API you will get a signifigant boost in speed.  Cocoa is always dealing with obj-c objects, which are much heavier to manipulate than simple primitive c data types (especially in the context of 2,000,000 loop iterations)

Comment: @user1795943 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html